# Access/VBA/SQL 3141 error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have an Access form tied to a linked SQL Server table, and I'm trying to create a utility within access that creates new records in the SQL Server database from existing records; those of which match criteria from three selections in the Access form.

I'm not great with Access, SQL, or VBA, so that's cool, but here's what I have in VBA:

```vb
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = _
"SELECT *" _
& " INTO #MyTempTable" _
& " FROM ACCTLive1.dbo.BUDGET_ACCESS_Data1" _
& " WHERE Project_ID = '" & Forms!Utilities!comboMoveProjIDPID & "' " _
& " AND [Year] = '" & Forms!Utilities!txtMoveProjIDSourceYear & "' " _
& " UPDATE #MyTempTable" _
& " SET [Year]  = '" & Forms!Utilities!txtMoveProjIDDestYear & "' " _
& " UPDATE #MyTempTable" _
& " SET Total_Amt = (([Total_Amt] * .02)+[Total_Amt])" _
& " INSERT INTO ACCTLive1.dbo.BUDGET_ACCESS_Data1" _
& " SELECT *" _
& " FROM #MyTempTable" _
& " DROP TABLE #MyTempTable"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

I get an error:

> Run-time 3141 error: the SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

I grabbed the SQL query from the Debug Watch, and ran it successfully from SSMS.

I apologize ahead of time, as I know most of these 3141 issues are due to commas in the wrong place, etc, but the fact that the query works fine from SSMS leads me to believe I'm missing something else.

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to start using parameterized queries. Not only does it protect you from sql injection it makes you code far more manageable. I would even say you should convert this to a stored procedure on your sql server and stop doing database work in the front end.

Comment: Noted.  Thanks for the recommendation.  I'll do some homework and figure that out.  Poor security practices aside (I promise I'm not taking that lightly), do you know what may be causing the error in question?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry about the error too much. There are so many bad things in this code that simply writing it correctly will eliminate the errors. Things like inserts with no column names, select * are example of sloppy and brittle code. I will post an example shortly of a better way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks man.  If a little humility makes me a safer employee, I'll take whatever you dish out.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @RemoWilliams Protecting against SQL Injection isn't just about security. It also protects you against stupid embarrassing bugs when Bob O'Neil wants to log into your system, or when Mrs.Null wants to change her password. That said why isn't `Project_ID` not a numeric field (or if it is, then why is it quoted)?

Comment: SQL Server SQL and MS Access SQL are not the same. Something can run perfectly fine is SSMS and not work at all in Access and vice versa. To start with, when using VBA, don't jumble multiple SQL statements into a single string. Format and execute each one in sequence. At the very least you will know which of these work and which give an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning this into a stored procedure would reap many benefits. Your code is more manageable and you would start separating this into a data layer and application layer.

Your code is far more complicated than it needs to be. There is no need for a temp table, just select the data you need in your insert statement. A much simplified version of this as a stored procedure would look something like this.

```sql
create procedure BUDGET_ACCESS_Data1_Insert
(
    @ProjectID int
    , @SourceYear int
    , @DestinationYear int
) as begin

    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO ACCTLive1.dbo.BUDGET_ACCESS_Data1
    (
        Column1
        , Column2
        , Total_Amt
        , [Year]
    )
    SELECT Column1
        , Column2
        , Total_Amt * 1.02 --This is a simplified version. 
        , @DestinationYear
    FROM ACCTLive1.dbo.BUDGET_ACCESS_Data1
    WHERE Project_ID = @ProjectID
        AND [Year] = @SourceYear

end
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'll work with this and let you know the results ASAP.

Comment: Cool. You will need to add and pass those parameters when calling this procedure from your VBA. One big advantage here is that if you decide to rewrite your front end at some point in something other than Access all you have to do is call the same procedure and it will still do all the data work for you.

Comment: I had to spend a little time educating myself on passing access form names as parameters in VBA, but it worked great once I got it figured out.  Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do a `SELECT INTO`, and `UPDATE`, another `UPDATE`, and `INSERT` and a `DROP TABLE` on Access tables. And this executing in Access not SQL Server tables because `CurrentDb.Execute` runs against your accdb not whatever you may have linked (remember you can have any number of linked data sources so it's not making any guesses for you).

Access will only process one statement at a time. Access also doesn't support `#Temp` tables.

You can execute this in SQL Server as a Pass Through query using ADO and it'll work but you should parameterize it like other answers have suggested already. There are many ways to go about this (stored procedure, ADO pass through query, QueryDef pass through query).

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate this information and it was no doubt the cause of the immediate issue.  I will use this info for future reference.  I gave the answer to Sean above, as he provided an elegant solution that worked successfully (and I already accepted it).  thanks again

Comment: @RemoWilliams no problem. Good luck!